# Twitter Framework on iOS - Posting Tweets

Tags: ios, permissions, twitter, user-permissions

Since the Twitter Framework handles the login authentication, does that mean I can freely post a tweets to the user's wall?

Since logging into twitter through the settings page gives permission access to all games, what if some games abuse it and spam a user's twitter page? If the user gets spammed and wants to block only that game, is that possible?

My game will be doing automatic posts whenever a user accomplishes something, should I be asking for permission every time before posting a tweet? or should I simply post a tweet and hope it's not seen as spam?

Comment: I would highly recommend you don't automatically tweet something. Nothing will anger your players than that. When they've done something in the game, ask if they want to tweet it.  Make it super easy for them to do, but don't automatically do it (if that is even possible).

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just curious, but is it possible to block a single application from twitter?

Answer (score 2):

You can show the tweet dialog to the user, and that would post it for you.  It is fairly easy to do this, here is a great tutorial for how:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6